# Change String Array to List<String> - Java/Android

Tags: java, android, string, list

I am updating a custom adapter and had to change the value from a String Array to a List.

Here is code:

```
private final List<String> values;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comments_listadapter, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.comments_label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.comments_menu);
    textView.setText(values[position]); // Needs to Change!

    String s = values[position]; // Needs to Change!

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.up_down);

    return rowView;
}
```

I have marked the two lines that need to change (I am not sure if changing it to a List will need more to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for:

```
String s = values.get(position);
textView.setText(s);
```

Comment: If the answer worked out for you, don't forget to mark it as correct; it helps others find the answer in the future!

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> mStringList = Arrays.asList(values);
```

where values is a string array. 
Arrays class is in `java.util package`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String s = getItem(position);
textView.setText(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you have something like `String[] values` which you want to be `List<String> values`.

Here is how you can do the conversion:

```
List<String> listValues = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String s : values) {
    listValues.add(s);
}
```

Then instead of `values[position]`, you do `listValues.get(position)`.

Comment: shortcut for you have:   List<String> listValues = Arrays.asList(values);    :)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your problem?
Do you mean you have to change your references to

```
mList.get(position);
mList.add(position, string);
```